# Python unicode decoding encoding

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, decoding

Here is my full code, and it is working fine with ASCII, but when comes the "unicode" charaters in the picture... I hate my life...

I know this is not english, but let me explain:

I have got 2 input files (realmek, nevek), and 1 result file (osszes).

I have got a working page in (html).

- Like I said with ANSI characters this is working.

BUT when I try use strange chracters: "űáéđĐ" I need to save 2 input, and 1 output files in UNICODE. But than my program drops a "encoding decoding" error. And I know it is normal.

So my question is: **How can I solve this? where I need to handle decoding encoding?**

I am thinking about this for 3 days... I tried many decoding, like "u = unicode( s, "utf-8" )" ; $ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; etc. But it didn't worked.

```
from urllib import urlopen
import re

faj = "hiba"
cast = "hiba"
pont = 0
szint = 0

fj = open("C:\Users\Rendszergazda\Desktop\Achievements\Realmek.txt", "r")
tombr = fj.readline()
realmek = tombr.split(" ")
fj.close()

fh = open("C:\Users\Rendszergazda\Desktop\Achievements\Nevek.txt", "r")
tomb = fh.readline()
nevek = tomb.split(" ")
fh.close()

osszes = open("C:\Users\Rendszergazda\Desktop\Achievements\Osszes.txt", "a")

for x in realmek:
    realm = x
    for y in nevek:
        nev = y
        lap = urlopen("http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/"+str(realm)+"/"+str(nev)+"/achievement").read()
        letezik = re.compile('<div id="server-erro(.*)">')
        letez = re.findall(letezik,lap)
        if (letez != []):   
            a = 0    
        else:

            lapn = lap.split("\n")      
            mapo = lapn[1087]
            pontos = re.compile('\t\t\t\t\t(.*)\r')
            pont = re.findall(pontos,mapo)

            mapom = lapn[1322]
            feastn = re.compile('<div class="bar-contents">\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(.*)\r')
            feast = re.findall(feastn,mapom)

            fajkeres = re.compile('</strong></span> <a href="/wow/en/game/race/(.*)" class="race">')
            castkeres = re.compile('</a> <a href="/wow/en/game/class/(.*)" class="class">')
            szintkeres = re.compile('<span class="level"><strong>(.*)</strong></span> <a href="/wow/en/game/')

            faj  = re.findall(fajkeres,lap)
            cast = re.findall(castkeres,lap)
            szint = re.findall(szintkeres,lap)        
            link = "http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/"+str(realm)+"/"+str(nev)+"/advanced"

            ccast = cast [0]
            ffaj = faj [0]
            sszint = szint [0]
            ppont = pont [0]
            ffeast = feast [0]

            osszes.write(str(nev)+" "+str(realm)+" "+str(ppont)+" "+str(ffeast)+" "+str(ffaj)+" "+str(ccast)+" "+str(sszint)+" "+str(link)+"\n")      

osszes.close()
```

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". Do you get unexpected output, an exception, a crash, ... Please edit the error details into your question.

Comment: It doesn't give any error, just give a stack overflow, because the UNICODE characters not will be in the same spot, example: mapo = lapn[1087] with ASNII give '16', and with UNICODE source input: give unicode stings... and where I need to decoding before I use .write 

SO the problem, not the error, because I know what is the error, the problem is the encoding, but I don't know where I need to encode first the inputs.

Comment: I had some problems like those and I resolve. Encoding is, in a kind of way, very problematic. Take a look to mine question about it and try to extract suggestions from those. Good luck!

Comment: You code isn't a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) so it's hard for us to help.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of plain open, use `codecs.open` to read and write your file. They take an optional argument that you use to specify what encoding to use. Ensure that you can read, print and write non-ascii text correctly (it will be seen as unicode inside your script), and *afterwards* check whether you're using any regexps that need adjustment.

Also, if you're using any non-ascii characters in your python source, declare your script's encoding by adding something like this as the first or second line:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```